# Can I do a conditional sort on two different columns, but where the order of two columns is reversed based on the secondary condition?

Tags: python, list, sorting

### Edit: Since writing this, I remembered a third necessary condition. That is, if the difference between the values at index 1 (time) is greater than or equal to 2, then the rows should be sorted normally by the index 1 (time) column. So because the time value for B is 6 and within a difference of 2 for the T time of 5, B should come after T. However,for T and K, for example, because the 7 value for K is 2 greater than the 5 value for T, T should come first.

Let's say I have this array

```
input = [['user_id', 'time', 'address'], 
    ['F', 5, 5], 
    ['T', 5, 8],
    ['B', 6, 6], 
    ['K', 7, 7], 
    ['J', 7, 9], 
    ['M', 9, 10]]
```

I'd like to sort the rows -- first in ascending order by index 1 (time). However, secondarily, if index 2 (address) for a given user_id such as 'B' is less than index 2 (address) for another user such as 'T', I'd like user_id 'B' to come before user_id 'T'.

So the final output would look like this:

```
output = [['user_id', 'time', 'address'], 
        ['F', 5, 5],
        ['B', 6, 6]
        ['T', 5, 8],
        ['K', 7, 7], 
        ['J', 7, 9], 
        ['M', 9, 10]]
```

If possible, I'd like to do this without Pandas.

Comment: You shouldn't name variables `input`, it overrides a builtin

Comment: Can you explain why `K` shouldn't come before `T` as well?  It seems like your condition is met for that column.  I think you just want something like `sorted(arr[1:], key=lambda x: (x[2], x[1]))`

Comment: The second list looks as if it is sorted using `time + address`

Comment: @user3483203 Very good question. I forgot to include a third, important condition that shows why K shouldn't come before T. That is, if the difference between the values at index 1 (time) is greater than or equal to 2, then the rows should be sorted by the index 1 (time) column. So for T and K, because the 7 value for K is 2 greater than the 5 value for T, T should come first. Does this change how the code should be doone?

Comment: @user3483203 And thanks for the heads up about input as a builtin. It slipped my mind about input being a builtin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> import functools
>>> 
>>> def compare(item1, item2):
...     return item1[1]-item2[1] if item1[1]-item2[1] >=2 else item1[2]-item2[2]
... 
>>> 
>>> output = [input[0]] + sorted(input[1:], key = functools.cmp_to_key(compare))
>>> pprint (output)
[['user_id', 'time', 'address'],
 ['F', 5, 5],
 ['B', 6, 6],
 ['T', 5, 8],
 ['K', 7, 7],
 ['J', 7, 9],
 ['M', 9, 10]]
>>>
```

Comment: Hi @sunitha. I forgot to include a third, important condition that shows why K shouldn't come before T even though B should come before T. That is, if the difference between the values at index 1 (time) is greater than or equal to 2, then the rows should be sorted by the index 1 (time) column. So for T and K, because the 7 value for K is 2 greater than the 5 value for T, T should come first. But for B and T, B comes before T because 6 is only 1 greater than 7, so the time difference between B and T is within less than 2. Does this change how the code should be done?

Comment: Updated the answer as per your requirements

Answer (score -2):

For builtin function `sorted` you can provide custom `key` method. Here it's enough if the key method returns a tuple of columns 1 and 2, so first the value of column 1 will be considered, and for rows having the same value in that column, will be ordered by column 2.

```
data = [['user_id', 'time', 'address'],
    ['F', 5, 5],
    ['B', 6, 6],
    ['T', 5, 8],
    ['K', 7, 7],
    ['J', 7, 9],
    ['M', 9, 10]]

data_sorted = [data[0]] + sorted(data[1:], key = lambda row: (row[1], row[2]))
```

Comment: This code doesn't even run.  You have a syntax error in your list declaration.  This also doesn't have `data[0]` as a sublist but instead as 3 elements.  Finally, and probably most importantly, it doesn't match the desired output

Comment: Hi @deenes. I forgot to include a third, important condition that shows why K shouldn't come before T even though B should come before T. That is, if the difference between the values at index 1 (time) is greater than or equal to 2, then the rows should be sorted by the index 1 (time) column. So for T and K, because the 7 value for K is 2 greater than the 5 value for T, T should come first. But for B and T, B comes before T because 6 is only 1 greater than 7, so the time difference between B and T is within less than 2. Does this change how the code should be done?

Comment: Hi @TJE, In this case @sunitha's answer with `functools.cmp_to_key()` is the best option. The method you supply as `key` argument for `sorted` has access to each of the elements one-by-one hence you have control over what you compare at sorting. With `cpm_to_key` you can pass a method which actually does the comparison, i.e. you can overwrite the comparison operators.